# BeautifulSoup4 extract all types of conditional comments

Tags: python, internet-explorer, beautifulsoup, conditional-comments, html5lib

### What i try to do:

Remove suspicious comments from html mails with bs4. Now i encountered a problem with so called `conditional comments` of type `downlevel-revealed`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v=vs.85)#syntax-of-conditional-comments

```
import bs4

html = 'A<!--[if expression]>a<![endif]-->' \
       'B<![if expression]>b<![endif]>'


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)):
    comment.extract()
```

### Befor extract comments:

```
'A',
'[if expression]>a<![endif]',
'B',
'[if expression]',
'b',
'[endif]',
```

### After extract comments:

```
'A',
'B',
'b',
```

### Problem:

The small b should also be removed. Problem is, bs4 detects first comment as one single comment object, but second is detected as 3 objects. Comment(if), NavigableString(b) and Comment(endif). Extraction just removes the both comment types. NavigableString with content 'b' remains in DOM.

*Any solution to this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of reading about conditional comments i can understand why this is happening this way.

#### downlevel-hidden

`downlevel-hidden` are basically written as normal comment `<!-- ... -->`. This is detected as conditional comment block in modern browsers. So BeautifulSoup removes it completely if i like to remove conditional comments.

#### downlevel-revealed

`downlevel-revealed` are written as `<!...>b<!...>`, modern browsers detect the two tags as invalid and ignore them in DOM, so just `b` remains valid. So BeautifulSoup removes only the tags, not the content

## Conclusion

BeautifulSoup handles conditional comments as modern browsers would do. This is perfectly fine for my circumstances.